# Is there a way to have already typed text after the input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to create a program so I can ask the user a question, and there is some text that appears inside the response area. This text should be deletable by the user.

Normally, when you use input("text") in Python, it only asks the user for a response. I didn't really expect anything different.

Comment: Could python's built in curses module help: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do it.

```
from pyautogui import typewrite

print("How are you?")
typewrite("Bad")
folder = input()
```

That will result in the text "How are you" printed and non editable and the text "Bad" printed but editable.